# Extracting Domains from E-mail Database List

Tags: python, computer-science, google-colaboratory

I need to extract the domains from emails in a dataset and count the top 5 domains.

```
import re
from collections import Counter
with open("emails")
domain = re.search('@[\w.)]+, email')
 print(domain.group())

 jbutt@gmail.com  http://www.bentonjohnbjr.com
 josephine_darakjy@darakjy.org  http://www.chanayjeffreyaesq.com
 art@venere.org http://www.chemeljameslcpa.com
 lpaprocki@hotmail.com  http://www.feltzprintingservice.com
 donette.foller@cox.net http://www.printingdimensions.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes list of top 5 domain:

```
import re
from collections import Counter 
resultList = []
with open("emails", "r") as email:
    for x in email:
        result = re.search('@(.*) ', x)
        resultList.append(result.group(1))
occurence_count = Counter(resultList) 
print(occurence_count.most_common(5))
```

Output:

```
[('gmail.com ', 1), ('darakjy.org ', 1), ('venere.org', 1), ('hotmail.com ', 1), ('cox.net', 1)]
```

Output is 5 most common domain names